# Bootstrap Modal not working on User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, bootstrap-modal

I've got an ASP.NET web page that creates a series of User Controls with varying data. Each User Control utilizes Bootstrap 3 Modal controls for a better user experience. I've double checked all of the tags are in the correct format. Some of the modals on the page work, but the modals in the User Controls do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP server controls using `runat="server"` will receive a unique client ID when served to the client. This means that any modal dialogs using the `runat="server"` attribute will potentially lose its connection with an element that toggles the modal using `data-target`.

For example, your code can look like this:

```
<button type="button" data-target="#modOverlay" id="btnShowOverlay" runat="server" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal">Show Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="modOverlay" runat="server">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        Some Modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Some Info/Data
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the above code is placed in a User Control, both the button and modal dialog IDs will change because of `runat="server"`.

Note that a similar issue will occur as a result of using a modal in a User Control. If multiple User Controls of the same build are used in a single page, then the `data-target` can overlap. Often times, the first dialog to be processed will be used. This means that if you have a server control, such as a button, in the dialog then you may run into issues with the wrong server button being clicked.

### Fix

Here's my fix for the issue. Please note that this will only be effective if the button (or whichever control) that targets the modal is within the same layer of controls (ie User Control, Web Page).

```
// Fix all dynamically generated controls' modal buttons
$(document).ready(function () { // Wait for the page to load all controls
  var fix_modals = $("button[data-toggle='modal'][data-target]"); // Get all <button> elements that target a modal
  for (var len = fix_modals.length, n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    var el = $('[id=' + fix_modals[n].id.slice(0,fix_modals[n].id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1) + fix_modals[n].getAttribute("data-target").slice(1) + ']'); // Try to find the modal using the button's data-target value and its own control prefix
    if (el != undefined) { // Verify that we found a control
      if (el.attr("role") == "dialog") { // verify that the control is a dialog
        fix_modals[n].setAttribute("data-target", "#" + el.attr("id")); // Fix the button's data-target to the client id
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to set ClientIDMode="Static" in the modal - runat="server" div? This prevent the twisted id generation and maybe the button would work.
I mean that the div would become:
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="modOverlay" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">